# Difference between getting URL query string with $routeParams vs $location.$$search

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

If I have a specific route parameter that is **always** being passed as a query string, is there a difference between retrieving the param using angular's `$routeParams` service and using its `$location.$$search` service?  If so, is one preferable to the other?

URL: `//localhost:80/app/profile?id=42`

`$routeParams` approach:

```
app.controller('ProfileController', ['$routeParams', function($routeParams) {
  console.log($routeParams.id);
}]);
```

`$location` approach:

```
app.controller('ProfileController', ['$location', function($location) {
  console.log($location.$$search.id);
}]);
```

I am already injecting `$location` as a dependency in the controller that needs to perform the behavior detailed in the question.  Additionally, the controller's module does not yet have a dependency on `ngRoute`.

Comment: I thought the proper way to use location here was $location.search().id  also, far as I know, there isn't any preference to use one over the other as long as you get the data you need.

Comment: I do think I've mostly seen people use $location approach, I've seen routeParams used when you are injecting optional variables into the url like: myURL/:optionalVariable/

Answer (score 5):

If your route is of type:

```
when('page/:id')
```

then using $location search won't give you the ID in the search result. But $routesParams does.

But in case of query params ex:

```
when('page?key=value&key2=value2')
```

In this case, you can go for any of $location.search or $routeParams.

Comment: @hartz89 Hope this answered your question, if so please accept this answer!

Answer (score 1):

It also seems that the $location way is faster in some sense (which is only natural, since $routeParams uses $location to get its values).

To explain:
My site has a mode that's only meant to be used by kiosk tablets, whereas the normal use case is customers using their own devices. To differentiate, I initiate kiosk tablets by going to https://mysite.url/?kiosk, which triggers this (which runs on load):

```
if($routeParams.kiosk){
    $cookieStore.put("kiosk", true);
}
```

Now, this tended to fail, since $routeParams hadn't had time to become initialized that close to load. Switching to

```
if($location.search().kiosk){
    $cookieStore.put("kiosk", true);
}
```

mitigated that issue.

(My site is currently stuck on Angular 1.2.19, and was not put together by people who had all current best practices in mind. My example may or may not be relevant to modern projects coded by competent developers ;-) )