# Angularjs difference between $routeparams and $location

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
app.controller('GetData', function ($scope, $location, $routeParams)
{
var searchObject = $location.search();  
$scope.isActiveFromLocation = (searchObject.state == "active");      
$scope.isActiveFromRoute = ($routeParams.state == "active"); 
}
```

In the above code, I am trying to get data from url querystring www.testsite.com/#xyz?state=active with angularjs. I debugged and found that both the scope variables show same result. Which option would be best in this case to read the query string value? Any suggestions.

Comment: This is more of an opinionated answer seeking question i guess. Route params internally uses `location.search()` to get query params plus it considers path parameters as well. So which one you want to chose is upto you. I would probably go with routeparams because it serves 2 purposes and abstracts out `search()` call anyways.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26807271/difference-between-getting-url-query-string-with-routeparams-vs-location-sea